# converting large XML from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 with entities in external DTD

Tags: java, xml

### I have:

- 2.2GiB of uncompressed XML in ISO-8859-1, starting with

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp-2017-08-29.dtd">`

- the corresponding DTD which defines entities as follows:

`<!ENTITY Aacute  "&#193;" ><!-- capital A, acute accent -->`

- a computer that cannot fit the parsed XML into RAM

### I want

To import the XML into Apache Solr, which is already set-up and working.
Solr/Java will (rightfully) complain about too many expanded entities, which I can raise by setting `-DentityExpansionLimit=2000000` for the JVM, but I'd have to edit the Importer to raise the limit with `System::setProperty`.

### I tried

#### xmllint

`xmllint --stream --loaddtd --encode utf8 --output dblp.utf8.xml dblp-2018-07-01.xml`

without `--stream` the process is killed by the kernel as it tries to parse the structure into memory.

with `--stream` it will not write the output file, I suspect it's only validating the XML against the DTD.

#### edit XML, python

I could not figure out how to import the DTD with python and use it with the parser, so I've put the entities into the `<!DOCTYPE dblp [ … ]>` and then

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree
f = open('dblp-2018-07-01.xml')
out = open('dblp.utf8.xml','wb')
xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(f).write(out, encoding='UTF-8')
```

This will consume roughly 11 GiB of memory and *works for me*, but:

### The details

I want others to reproduce what I am doing, so here's what I'd like to have:

- no editing the XML manually to insert entities
- a script or compiled program that can convert the encoding
- use as little memory as feasible, try to keep it below 6 GiB
- an added bonus would be reading from and writing to gzipped files to conserve space, but that's not necessary.

I'd prefer Java for a programmatic solution (so I can incorporate the import process into Solr), but I'll gladly take any other solutions (I'd like to avoid JavaScript).

If you want to screw around with the XML yourself, the files are located here:

- http://dblp.org/xml/release/ (use the latest dtd).
- http://dblp.org/faq/How+to+parse+dblp+xml.html (for more info).
- http://dblp.org/faq/Under+what+license+is+the+data+from+dblp+released.html (for the license).

The gzipped files are about 430MiB in size and expand to 2.2GiB of XML.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried reading, decoding to unicode, replacing entities  via regular expressions, encoding and writing?

Comment: I thought about reading/writing linewise, but I did not try. Mostly, because I am unsure wether I'd be doing the de/encoding correctly. XML is very picky and I'd rather not deal with that. I'm also unsure if using regular expressions would be the 'right thing' to do here, I have a hunch it isn't :D

Comment: Reading linewise is no problem if using "newline" end of line char and writing it back unchanged, although lines can beome quite long this way.
If entity expansion itself is implemented correctly then the result after parsing will stay the same.
Using a full blown XML parser is a safe choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself, it's a tad slow (~11-12 minutes) but I'm fine with it:

```
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

public class ConvertToUtf8 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("entityExpansionLimit", "10000000");
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();

    try (
        FileInputStream ifs = new FileInputStream("dblp-2018-08-01.xml.gz"); 
        GZIPInputStream gzIn = new GZIPInputStream(ifs);
        FileOutputStream ofs = new FileOutputStream("dblp_utf8.xml.gz");
        GZIPOutputStream gzOut = new GZIPOutputStream(ofs, true);
        ) 
    {
      XMLEventReader inEvt = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(gzIn);
      XMLEventWriter outEvt = outputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(gzOut, "UTF-8");
      outEvt.add(inEvent);
    } catch (IOException | XMLStreamException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Using GZIP in/out will speed the process up significantly (6 times faster on my machine) as reading from disk will bottleneck the rest of the system.
If you want to replicate, make sure the DTD is in your working directory, otherwise the entities will not be replaced. Java will insert a comment to the XML, stating that it cannot find the DTD otherwise.

Building upon the answer of @janbrohl :

```
#! python3
import re
import gzip
from lxml import etree

# read the DTD with the lxml parser
dtd = etree.DTD('dblp-2017-08-29.dtd')
# build a dict with it for lookup
replacements = {x.name: x.content for x in dtd.entities()}

entity_re=re.compile('&(\w+);')

def resolve_entity(m):
    """
    This will replace the defined entities with their expansions from the DTD:
    '&Ouml;' will be replaced with '&#214;'.
    The entities that are already escaped with '&#[0-9]+;' should not be expanded,
    Ex: if some of the escapes produced the character '<', the XML would no longer be well formed.

    If the matched entity is not in the replacements, use the match as default
    """
    return replacements.get(m.group(1),f'&{m.group(1)};')

def expand_line(line):
    return entity_re.sub(resolve_entity,line)

def recode_file(src,dst):
    with gzip.open(src,mode='rt', encoding='ISO-8859-1', newline='\n') as src_file:
        # discard first line with wrong encoding
        print('discard: ' + src_file.readline())  
        with gzip.open(dst, mode='wt', encoding='UTF-8', newline='\n') as dst_file:
            # replace with correct encoding statement
            dst_file.write('<?xml version="1.0"?>\n')  
            for line in src_file:
                dst_file.write(expand_line(line))

recode_file('dblp-2018-08-01.xml.gz','dblp_recode.xml.gz')
```

I've imported the output produced by the regex-replace, seems to be working :D 
Granted, it's faster than the Java version, but I'm still uncertain if the resulting XML is the same as the version that went through an actual parser.
I'll experiment a bit.

edit: after some experiments, I've discovered some edge cases that might modify the data. I'll leave the python script here, since it is fast.
But, I prefer using the version that actually uses a parser: it's easy to follow, uses only standard library and is easy to maintain.
The edge case was my fault, I used python's dict like you'd do in C++ maps: where accessing `replacements['val']` would create the entry in C++, `replacements.at('val')` will throw. In python, it's the other way round: `replacements['val']` will throw, `replacements.get('val')` won't and returns an empty string if no defaults were provided.

I'll leave this open for a little longer, in case somebody can find a faster solution.
edit: If somebody can find a faster solution that will use an XML parser :D

Comment: Actually the regex-approach should work almost as well in Java as in Python, just with more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

3 Minutes on my machine.

```
#! python3
import re
import gzip
import html.entities

entities={k:v for k,v in html.entities.entitydefs.items() if v not in "&'\"<>"}

entity_re=re.compile("&([^;]+);")    

def resolve_entity(m):
    try:
        return entities[m.group(1)]
    except KeyError:
        return m.group(0)    

def expand_line(line):
    return entity_re.sub(resolve_entity,line)

def recode_file(src,dst):
    with gzip.open(src,mode="rt", encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline="\n") as src_file:
        with gzip.open(dst, mode="wt", encoding="UTF-8", newline="\n") as dst_file:
            first_line=src_file.readline()
            recoded_first_line=first_line.replace("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8")
            if first_line==recoded_first_line:
                raise ValueError("Source file seems to not be encoded in ISO-8859-1") 
            dst_file.write(recoded_first_line)
            for line in src_file:
                dst_file.write(expand_line(line))


recode_file("D:/Downloads/dblp-2018-08-01.xml.gz","D:/Downloads/dblp.xml.gz")
```

Comment: I've proposed some modifications, so the entities defined in the DTD will be replaced as well. Otherwise `&ouml;` and friends will remain. I've also replaced the first line to state the correct encoding, the XMLReaders are enforcing the stated encoding. I'll try to import the produced XML to Solr to see if there are any differences. Will report back.

Comment: I actually totally misread the DTD before. Numbered entities like `&#100;` are now left untouched.